# If the limit as $x$ approaches $3$ of $x^2$ is $9$, how do I use the epsilon delta definition to prove this?

Tags: calculus

If the limit as $x$ approaches $3$ of $x^2$ is $9$, how do I use the epsilon delta definition to prove this? I was trying to work it out this way but could do figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $$|x^2-9|=|x-3||x+3|=|x-3||x-3+6|\le|x-3|^2+6|x-3|,$$ so given $\epsilon>0,$ we need only find $\delta>0$ small enough so that $|x-3|^2<\frac\epsilon2$ and $6|x-3|<\frac\epsilon2$ whenever $|x-3|<\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^2-9=(x-3)(x+3)$. Given $\epsilon>0$ try $\delta=\min\{1,\frac\epsilon4\}$. Note that then $|x-3|<\delta$ implies $0<x+3<4$.

Comment: any reason you chose the min to be that?